# Добавление аргумента в сериализатор

Tags: django-rest-framework

Делаю Канбан-доску и со страницы прилетают `2` аргумента по `PATCH`-запросу:

- pk задачи
- boardName - наименование доски на которую переместили задачу.

Поля `boardName` у меня в моделях нет, но есть аналог `Status`. Мне нужно обработать прилетевшие со страницы данные о задачи и в сериализатор отправить `pk` и дату (поле `DateTime_schedule`) чтобы обновить поле `DateTime_schedule`.

Пытался переопределить метод `update` в `KanbanEProposalSerializer`, но отладить его не могу, точка останова его не видит.

Смотрел много примеров и вот что написал. Подскажите мне пожалуйста: как обновить поле `DateTime_schedule` датой полученной из куска кода в `partial_update()`.

**serializers.py**

```
class KanbanEProposalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = eproposals
        fields = '__all__'
        #('id', 'NumObject', 'AddressObject', 'Client_words', 'FaultAppearance', 'DescriptionWorks', # 'DateTime_schedule', 'DateTime_work', 'Status')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        print('this-here')
        task_data = eproposals.objects.get(pk=instance.id)
        eproposals.objects.filter(pk=instance.id).update(**validated_data)
        return task_data
```

**views.py**

```
class KanbanEProposalViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = KanbanEProposalSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
     ....

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data['DateTime_schedule'] = '2022-12-27'
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        pk = self.kwargs.get("pk")
        date_schedule = None
        board_name = request.data.get('boardName', None)
        task_data = eproposals.objects.get(pk=pk)
        currdate = datetime.now().date()
        if task_data.Status.Name == 'Принята' and board_name not in ['Завершено', 'Исполнено']:
            if board_name == 'Сегодня':
                date_schedule = currdate
            elif board_name == 'Завтра':
                date_schedule = currdate + timedelta(days=1)
            elif board_name == 'Понедельник':
                delta = 7 - currdate.isoweekday() + 1
                date_schedule = currdate + timedelta(days=delta)
        serialized = KanbanEProposalSerializer(request.user, data=request.data, partial=True)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

Answer (score 0):

Сам задал и сам о нашел решение на основе другой статьи на данном сайте.

1. Коментим def partial_update.
2. Переносим код определения даты в update в serialiser.
3. Добавляем Validate_data({'DateTime_schedule': date_schedule})
   return super().update(instance, validated_data)
   И всё работает.